# Java IllegalArgumentException when trying to run a program

Tags: java

I finished my java program, it compiles with no problems, but when I try to run it on a MacBook with JRE 6, I get this error. I am not the best at reading this, but I believe the error comes from my card layout.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string
    at java.awt.CardLayout.addLayoutComponent(CardLayout.java:190)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1072)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:363)
    at RPS.<init>(RPS.java:75)
    at RPS.main(RPS.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

It ran before on my PC with JRE 7, but now it gives me issues. Here is the my code.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class RPS extends JFrame {

  ButtonGroup P1choices, P2choices;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   new RPS();
  }
   public RPS() {
super("Rock, Paper, Scissors");

setSize(300,300);
setResizable(false);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);

final CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout(10,10);
final JPanel cardPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

final JRadioButton P1Rock = new JRadioButton("Rock");
final JRadioButton P1Paper = new JRadioButton("Paper");
final JRadioButton P1Scissors = new JRadioButton("Scissors");

final JRadioButton P2Rock = new JRadioButton("Rock");
final JRadioButton P2Paper = new JRadioButton("Paper");
final JRadioButton P2Scissors = new JRadioButton("Scissors");

JButton nextButton = new JButton("Next");
JButton finish = new JButton("Finish");

P1choices = new ButtonGroup();
P1choices.add(P1Rock);
P1choices.add(P1Paper);
P1choices.add(P1Scissors);

P2choices = new ButtonGroup();
P2choices.add(P2Rock);
P2choices.add(P2Paper);
P2choices.add(P2Scissors);

final JLabel statusLabel = new JLabel(" ");
JLabel P1turn = new JLabel("It is Player 1's turn. Choose:");
JLabel p2turn = new JLabel("It is Player 2's turn. Choose:");

panel1.add(P1turn);
panel1.add(P1Rock);
panel1.add(P1Paper);
panel1.add(P1Scissors);
panel1.add(nextButton);
panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

panel2.add(p2turn);
panel2.add(P2Rock);
panel2.add(P2Paper);
panel2.add(P2Scissors);
panel2.add(finish);
panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

cardPanel.add(panel1);
cardPanel.add(panel2);

add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(statusLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    cardLayout.next(cardPanel);
}
});
finish.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (P1Rock.isSelected() && P2Scissors.isSelected()){
     statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins! Rock crushes Scissors.");
   } 
    if (P1Rock.isSelected() && (P2Paper.isSelected())) {
     statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins! Paper covers Rock.");
   }
    if (P1Rock.isSelected() && (P2Rock.isSelected())) {
     statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
   }
    if (P1Paper.isSelected() && P2Rock.isSelected()){
     statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins! Paper covers Rock.");
   }
    if (P1Paper.isSelected() && P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins! Scissors cut Paper.");
   }
    if (P1Paper.isSelected() && P2Paper.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
   }
    if (P1Scissors.isSelected() && P2Paper.isSelected()){
     statusLabel.setText("Player 1 wins! Scissors cut Paper.");
   }
    if (P1Scissors.isSelected() && P2Rock.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("Player 2 wins! Rock crushes Scissors.");
   }
    if (P1Scissors.isSelected() && P2Scissors.isSelected()) {
     statusLabel.setText("It's a tie!");
   }
 }
});
  }
}
```

Please let me know what I can do to fix this. Thanks!

EDIT:
My home PC runs JRE 7, but the error occurred on my school Macbooks. I believe those are running JRE 6 because we can't do updates without administrative rights and our technology director was arrested.

Comment: But he's not passing a `BorderLayout` in.  `BorderLayout.CENTER` is defined as a `String` and its value is `"Center"` (checking the source).  Unless there's a different `BorderLayout` class getting imported?

Comment: What JRE version are you using?  I use version 7 and the line numbers in your stack trace don't match the sources I have at all.

Comment: I think @ajb has a good point. Even i got tricked by your question. That is why it is constantly asked here for [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @ajb I know that I am running JRE 7 at home, but the error occurs at school. We use 2007 and 2009 MacBooks, but our district technology director was arrested and we haven't had updates in years (need administrative rights,) so I'd imagine that the error is between JRE 6 and JRE 7. Is there a happy medium that I can use to fix this?

Comment: @ZeroConnor I don't know... I do think `BorderLayout.CENTER` is a `String` in JRE 6 also, probably all the way back to 1.2.  I was really hoping to be able to look at the JRE sources looking at the line numbers in your backtrace to try to get some insight, but if you're using an old version then that would make things harder.

Comment: @ajb I can can guarantee that the computers were not updated since 2010, they run OS X 10.5 Leopard. Since JRE 7 was 2011, they can't be running it. So there must have been some sort of change between JRE 6 and 7 that caused the error.

Comment: @ZeroConnor I noticed this in another SO question: "JDK 7 is the first official JDK for Mac, all the previous JDKs are from Apple."  I wonder if that has something to do with it.

Comment: @ajb If that is the case, what can I do to fix the error?

Comment: @ZeroConnor no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in a string when you add items to your card layout:

```
cardPanel.add(panel1, "player1");
cardPanel.add(panel2, "player2");
```

You can then set which card is showing with:

```
cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player1");
```

or

```
cardLayout.show(cardPanel, "player2");
```

<sup>[(Tutorial)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)</sup>

Comment: Can I have more info on this? I don't know if it will fix my problem.

Comment: A `CardLayout` stacks multiple elements on top of each other (like a stack of cards), only showing the topmost one. You have to give the layout a name for each of the elements so that you can later tell it to move one to the top / make it visible.

Comment: But if it runs on JRE 7, I don't see how it would cause the error to occur on the Mac's unofficial JRE 6 (Apple made their own JRE up until JRE 7.)

Comment: @ZeroConnor I'm saying that the code you posted above is not using `CardLayout` correctly, and honestly should be throwing an error. They changed some of the default behavior in JRE 7 that makes it silently ignore errors. In JRE7, the `panel1` is added and then immediately replaced by `panel2` in the `cardPanel`, which is not the behavior you want I think.

Comment: Okay, that explains a lot. I can't test your solution until Wednesday, but if it works, that would be awesome. I wasn't trying to shoot down your suggestion, I just didn't know that JRE 7 ignored errors. I will look into it.

Comment: It's not so much that it ignores errors, as it uses the empty string (`""`) as a default constraint if you don't provide one.

Comment: I sacrificed my old PC and set it up to run JRE 6. Without the "player1/2" strings, I got the error. With the strings, it runs exactly how it was intended to work. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use a `BorderLayout` constraint for a `CardLayout`.

Look at the `CardLayout` documentation and find out what constraint you should be using.

Comment: I don't get this.  Unless the OP is using an incompatible JRE, both `BorderLayout` and `CardLayout` take objects of `String` type as constraints, and `BorderLayout.CENTER` is a `String`, so considering that `add` would have no idea where the `String` parameter comes from, why would it say `"constraint must be a string"`?

Comment: ZeroConnor is using a `BorderLayout` constraint when adding things to his `JFrame`... which uses a `BorderLayout` by default, so doing such is perfectly valid.